# How do I use variable substitution in a remote ssh command when the variable value has spaces in it?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I've got the following test script:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.1.10 'ls -l "aaa   bbb.txt"'

domain="aaa   bbb.txt"
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.1.10 \'ls -l "${domain}"\'
```

The first command without the $domain variable works fine. Returns:
`-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 7 Nov 21 22:49 aaa   bbb.txt`

What I can't figure out is the second command. Running it returns the following from the remote server: `bash: ls -l aaa   bbb.txt: command not found`

If I leave off the escaped backticks (`ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.1.10 ls -l "${domain}"`) I get the following error:

```
ls: cannot access 'aaa': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'bbb.txt': No such file or directory
```

How can I use variable substitution with spaces in the variable value in a remote ssh command?

Thanks.

Comment: try replacing quotes: ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.1.10 "ls -l '${domain}'"

Comment: You can use `echo` instead of `ssh ...` to see what'll be sent as a command to the remote shell (e.g. `echo "ls -l '${domain}'"` to test @MaximSagaydachny's suggestion). Usually, `echo` is a bad way to see what a command is doing, because it shows the result *after* parsing, which can be confusing. But in this case, it'll show what things like after the local shell has processed it, but before the remote shell has processed it.